# Google Chrome crashing on linux when trying to upload *.jpg file

Tags: google-chrome, crash, jpeg, segmentation-fault

I'm on Slackware 13.1, and installed Chrome 5.0.375.126 using [sbopkg](http://www.sbopkg.org/) from slackbuilds. Whenever I open the file upload dialog and select a *.jpg file, the browser immediately crashes, leaving behind a "Segmentation fault" error. I've done the same thing with other files, *.zip, *.png and *.gif and they didn't crash the browser, for some reason it only happens to *.jpg files, so far. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with libjpeg 6/7: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30288

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem for long time in ArchLinux. It's an issue with libjpeg linking (different libjpeg version on my system and different was used when building package).

I've switched to chromium (open-source version of chrome) and it works without any problems for long time. And it doesn't spy on you (sending data to google) like Chrome.

Comment: I'm using chromium on archlinux now and it still need libjpeg6 and crash all the time @.@